# How to change log4j appender at runtime?

Tags: log4j

I've got to do my rootLogger change at runtime in log4j, using setLevel method. But I need to change my appenders configurations too. The maxFileSize and maxBackupIndex. How I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to  load/parse the log4j properties at runtime. You could implement a thread class to load log4j properties file in configurable time period.